Why are types not recognizeable and why is there a segmentation fault?
I'm working on a C project involving abstract syntax tree (AST) structures for a compiler or interpreter. The project aims to parse a programming language and generate AST representations of the code for further processing.
I introduced a new structure in my project called _prog_tree, intended to represent a program within the AST ( i had to follow a given grammar). This structure includes fields for commande and programme, represented by AST_comm and AST_prog respectively.
here is the relevent code snippet
struct _prog_tree {
    AST_comm  commande;
    AST_prog programme;
};

typedef struct _prog_tree* AST_prog;

However, upon adding this structure and typedef to my project, I encountered compilation errors indicating that AST_comm and AST_prog are unknown types. Strangely, when I modify the typedef as follows:
typedef struct _prog_tree* AST_prog;

The compilation errors disappear, but I encounter a segmentation fault during runtime, specifically after the first six tokens are created by the lexer.
here is the parser.y file :
/* file parseur.y
* compilation: bison -d parseur.y
* result: parseur.tab.c = C code for syntaxic analyser
* result: parseur.tab.h = def. of lexical units aka lexems
*/
%{ // the code between %{ and %} is copied at the start of the generated .c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "AST.h"
int yylex(void); // -Wall : avoid implicit call
int yyerror(AST_comm**,int*, const char*); // on fonctions defined by the generator
int i = 1;
%}

%parse-param {AST_comm **rez} {int *size}
%union {AST_comm tree;
        AST_expr leaf;
        double number;
        bool boolean;
        char* string}
%token <number> NUMBER
%token ELSE
%token IF
%token WHILE
%type <leaf> expression
%type <tree> program
%type <tree> commande
%token <boolean> BOOLEAN
%token <string> IDENT
%start program
%right '='
%left EQ LEQ REQ NEQ '>' '<' AND
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc UMOINS '!' IMPORT
%%

program : 
            {
                
            }
        | commande program
        ;


commande:   expression ';' 
{
    if (*rez == NULL) {
        *rez = (AST_comm*)malloc(sizeof(AST_comm));
    } else {
        AST_comm *tmp = (AST_comm*)realloc(*rez, sizeof(AST_comm) * i);
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            free(*rez);
            return 0;
        }
        *rez = tmp;
    }
    if (*rez == NULL) {
        return 0; // Allocation failed
    }
    (*rez)[i-1] = new_command($1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    *size = ++i;
}

        | IMPORT IDENT ';' 
            {
                /*Ajouter lecture de fichier au niveau de code_gen*/
            }
        | '{' program '}'
           {
   
    $$ = $2;
          }

        | WHILE '(' expression ')' commande 
            {
               
                $$ = new_command(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                $$->rule = 'W'; 
                $$->expr1 = $3; 
                $$->com1 = $5; 
            }
        |IF '(' expression ')' commande ELSE commande
          {
    
          $$ = new_command(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
          $$->rule = 'Z';
          $$->expr1 = $3;
          $$->com1 = $5;
          $$->com2 = $7;
           }
          ;



             



expression:
    expression '+' expression
                {$$ = new_binary_expr('+',$1,$3, NULL);}
    | expression '-' expression
                {$$ = new_binary_expr('-',$1,$3, NULL);}
    | expression '*' expression
                {$$ = new_binary_expr('*',$1,$3, NULL);}
    | expression '/' expression
                {$$ = new_binary_expr('/',$1,$3, NULL);}
    | expression EQ expression
                {$$ = new_binary_expr('=',$1,$3, NULL);}
    | expression LEQ expression
                {$$ = new_binary_expr('L',$1,$3, NULL);}
    | expression REQ expression
                {$$ = new_binary_expr('R',$1,$3, NULL);}
    | expression NEQ expression
                {$$ = new_binary_expr('E',$1,$3, NULL);}
    | expression '<' expression
                {$$ = new_binary_expr('<',$1,$3, NULL);}
    | expression '>' expression
                {$$ = new_binary_expr('>',$1,$3, NULL);}
    | expression AND expression
                {$$ = new_binary_expr('&',$1,$3, NULL);}
    | '!' expression
                {$$ = new_unary_expr('!',$2, NULL);}
    | '(' expression ')'
                {$$ = $2;}
    | '-' expression %prec UMOINS
                {$$ = new_unary_expr('M',$2, NULL);}
    | IDENT '=' expression

                {$$ = new_unary_expr('A',$3, $1);}//Pour le moment je fais binaire mais il faut faire unary

    | NUMBER
                {$$ = new_number_expr($1);}
    | BOOLEAN
                {$$ = new_bool_expr($1);}
    | IDENT
                {$$ = new_str_expr($1);}
    ;
%% // denotes the end of the grammar
// everything after %% is copied at the end of the generated .c
int yyerror(AST_comm **rez, int *size, const char *msg){ // called by the parser if the parsing fails
printf("Parsing:: syntax error in \n");
return 1; // to distinguish with the 0 retured by the success
} 

and here is the lexer.l file :
/* file lexeur.l
* compilation: flex lexeur.l
* result: lex.yy.c = lexical analyser in C
*/
%{
#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include <stdbool.h> //bool
#include "AST.h"
#include "parser.tab.h" // token constants defined in parseur.y via #define
%}
SCI [0-9]+.[0-9]*[\e\E][\-\+]?[0-9]+|\.[0-9]+[\e\E][\-\+]?[0-9]+|[0-9]+[\e\E][\-\+]?[0-9]+

%%
[0-9]+\.[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+  {printf("lex: création token NUMBER %s\n",yytext);yylval.number=atof(yytext);
                    return NUMBER; }

{SCI}   {printf("lex: création token NUMBER sci %s\n",yytext);yylval.number=atof(yytext);
                    return NUMBER; }

NaN {printf("lex: création token NUMBER NaN\n");yylval.number=0.0 / 0.0;
                    return NUMBER;}
True    {printf("lex: création token BOOLEAN %s\n",yytext); yylval.boolean=true;
                    return BOOLEAN; }
False   {printf("lex: création token BOOLEAN %s\n",yytext); yylval.boolean=false;
                    return BOOLEAN; }


"if"     { printf("lex: création token IF\n"); return IF; }
else    { printf("lex: création token ELSE\n"); return ELSE; }
while    { printf("lex: création token WHILE\n"); return WHILE; }



"//"([a-z]|[0-9]|[A-Z]|[ ])*[\n]    { ; }
"/*"([a-z]|[0-9]|[A-Z]|[ \n])*"*/"  { ; }

import      {printf("lex: création token %s\n",yytext); return IMPORT;}
[a-z]([a-z]|[0-9]|[A-Z]|[_])*  {printf("lex: création token IDENT %s\n",yytext); yylval.string = strdup(yytext);
                    return IDENT; }

[ \t\r] { ; }

\n  {printf("lex: fin de lecture");
                    return 0;}

"=="    {printf("lex: création token %s\n",yytext); return EQ;} 

"<="    {printf("lex: création token %s\n",yytext); return LEQ;}    

">="    {printf("lex: création token %s\n",yytext); return REQ;}    

"!="    {printf("lex: création token %s\n",yytext); return NEQ;}
"&&"    {printf("lex: création token %s\n",yytext); return AND;}


.   {printf("lex: création token %s\n",yytext); return yytext[0];}  
%%
int yywrap(void){ return 1; } // function called at the end of the file



I'm seeking assistance in understanding why these issues are occurring and how to resolve them. Could the problem be related to incorrect inclusion of headers, struct declarations, or typedefs? Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

"Strangely, when I modify the typedef as follows:" The modified typedef looks identical to the original. But in the original it was defined after it had been referenced. Perhaps you just moved the typedef?

Do not hide pointer nature behind typedefs. It confuses and obscures much more than it helps.  In fact, you should minimize your use of typedefs in general, as most uses obfuscate more than they help, but hiding pointer nature is among the worst kinds of offences typedefs provide for.

@IanAbbott my phrasing was poor, i meant when i write the typedef, without defining the full structure struct _prog_tree {
AST_comm  commande;
AST_prog programme;
}; before, it doesn't work.

"I encountered compilation errors indicating that AST_comm and AST_prog are unknown types" -- this is a question of the scope of those identifiers, which is a function of the order in which they are defined in (I presume) AST.h.

The segmentation faults are likely due to some problem with the malloc and realloc calls. Perhaps the allocation/reallocation sizes are wrong?

Instead of messing with reallocation of array-like data structures, consider using linked lists.  That's a little harder to mess up, and more synergistic with AST structure.

You show the failing code:
struct _prog_tree {
    AST_comm commande;
    AST_prog programme;
};

typedef struct _prog_tree *AST_prog;

You don't define the name AST_prog until after you've used it, which does not work.
The fix is simple:
typedef struct _prog_tree *AST_prog;

struct _prog_tree {
    AST_comm commande;
    AST_prog programme;
};

This declares AST_prog as an alias for struct _prog_tree *.  At the end of the typedef, the compiler knows that there is a type struct _prog_tree defined somewhere, but as yet, the details are unknown.  At that point, it is an opaque type — without more information, you cannot create variables of type struct _prog_tree (but you can create pointers to such structures), and you cannot access any members of the structure (the compiler doesn't know what the members are yet).  The structure definition follows; now you can create structures and access the members of the structure.  Obviously, you also need to ensure that AST_comm is defined before struct _prog_tree is defined.

Caveats
You should consider the discussion in Is it a good idea to typedef pointers? — the short answer is usually "No".
Also, you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers says:


All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.
All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.


See also What does double underscore (__const) mean in C?

thank you @Jonathan for your answer, however, the problem still persists, i changed the order of the typedef of each structure, yet it doesn't seem to work

Since you've not yet provided the AST.h header, we can't test your code.  Please create an MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example
— or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example
— the same idea by a different name).
